# Calculated column to retrieve total number of ID

Tags: 2013, column, calculated-column, sharepoint-on-prem

I have a SharePoint list which all has a unique ID to identify the items, so I want to create a calculated column that counts how many ID are there, like a count!

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The ID field is usually automatically assigned by the system. As long as you don't delete an entry, the new ID number shows how much entry you have.
2. A calculated field is "calculated" only when you edit/save the entry. It would not automatically re-calculate. Assume you have a way to get the total number of entries, the total number of entries stored in the current entry would not be automatically updated if you add more entries later on.
3. Or you have to do one or more workflow, so that when one entry is added to the list, the workflow would run on every entry to update the count field for each entry. (one workflow to update the count field when the entry is updated, another workflow, defined with a different list to find the next not updated entry and trigger a change of it, stop when all entry updated)

add comments if you need more details on #3

On #3, there are two topics, 
A. To get the count of total entry numbers
B. To update the counted number on the field (e.g. "count") of the list.

About A.
I think we can do this with CAML query. Check [link here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/28c5b50c-912b-46be-81ed-5c104197326b/how-to-get-the-count-of-items-in-a-list-for-a-workflow?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy), and [this one](http://spthoughts.wordpress.com/category/counting-items/) for example. 
Or e.g. in Nintex workflow, simply do a "Query list" to get a collection of the ID field, and "Collection operation" with count. 
[image: Collection operation]

About B.
Say we are working with list X, and we define a "control" list called Y. 
At each creation/modification of entry of X, we trigger a workflow Wx, which is just to update a whatever field defined entry in list Y, just to trigger Wy.

At each modification of entry of Y, we trigger a workflow Wy, which is to do the count of entries in list X, find an entry in list X, of which the "count" doesn't match the new count number, and update that entry in X with the new count number, and stop the Wy, but because of the entry in X is updated, the Wy will be triggered again.

In Wy, you will have to add logic/condition to stop the workflow Wy when there's no X entry found, to avoid infinitive loop.

By the way "count" field in X here is not a calculated field, but just a number field.

Comment: Yes I need more details and help on #3

Comment: @Puseletso added more details, will have to go for lunch first...

Comment: Thank so much...I owe you one..

Comment: @Puseletso added links that could be helpful on point A.

Comment: @ Gao Wei one more thing what kind of action should I use could you kindly give me an example,am using nintex workflow in SharePoint 2013 on prem

Comment: @Puseletso e.g. "Query list", and store result in a workflow variable (collection), "For each" collection, "Math operation" counter (number) plus 1; "Set field value", and "Query list", filter "fieldA" in "List X" equal to "fieldB" in "list Y"

Comment: @ Gao Wei sorry to ask too many question,about the for each action, inside the for each action what should I put/use inside there

Comment: @Puseletso I think the version that I'm using is an earlier nintex, anyway, you would have to create the workflow variable first, one collection (e.g. c), one number (e.g. n), and in the "Query list" select which list, field to query, and filter, to store it to the collection, and in the "for each", you can select for each c, do a "math" and etc. And in the "Set Field Value", select table, field and etc.

Comment: @ Gao Wei for some how its not returning the total ID No its returning 0 I don't know were is the problem,Kindly help

Comment: the Math action should it be inside the for each or after the for each?

Comment: @Puseletso Sorry, it should be "Collection operation", and select "count" and store the result in workflow variable.

Comment: @Puseletso picture attached in the answer

Comment: Thank you I kinda figured that out after 3-5 hours of getting errors,Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You can't, calculated columns only operate on the current item. You could create a grouped view and use the Totals section to add a count to a field.